# Not able to perform transformations on Kinesis input Dstream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to consume a kinesis stream and perform transformations on it with spark streaming, but not getting results.

Now below code in if clause works fine. when I get non zero records in the stream it prints the count.
If I use logger.warn("") in the if-clause in case of print statements, I just keep on getting below lines in my log and not the actual count:

*INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1547121901568 in memory on ip-10-225-172-215.ec2.internal:37820*

No idea why spark fails to execute count() when logger is used.

Also till now I'm able to save the **str rdd** to hdfs.
My stream is outputting records in json format.

Now If I try to parse my stream as json and load like below code, again I get nothing but below info in my log:

*INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1547121901577 in memory on ip-10-225-172-70.ec2.internal:39438 (size: 6.4 MB, free: 1238.7 MB)
 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1547121901578 in memory on ip-10-225-172-215.ec2.internal:37820 (size: 5.1 MB, free: 1233.6 MB)
 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1547121901578 in memory on ip-10-225-172-70.ec2.internal:39438 (size: 5.1 MB, free: 1233.6 MB)
 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1547121755000 ms*

Here's the code I'm using:

```
object KinesisWatch {


  val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger("##### Kinesis-Logs #####")
  Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.INFO)
  Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager").setLevel(Level.INFO)
  logger.setLevel(Level.INFO)

  // Kinesis, AWS and Spark streaming configurations
  val kinesisConfig = Map(
    ("appName", "spark-kinesis"),
    ("streamName", "xxxx"),
    ("endpointUrl", "https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"),
    ("numStreams", "2"),
    ("regionName", "us-east-1"),
    ("awsAccessKey", "xxxxx"),
    ("awsSecretKey", "xxxxxx"),
    ("sparkStreamingBatchInterval", "5"),
    ("kinesisCheckpointInterval", "5"))

  logger.warn("Setting up SparkConfig and StreamingContext")
  val sparkSession = new SparkSessionWrapper().sparkSession
  val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
  val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(kinesisConfig("sparkStreamingBatchInterval").toInt))

  val awsCredentials = SparkAWSCredentials.builder.basicCredentials(kinesisConfig("awsAccessKey"), kinesisConfig("awsSecretKey"))

  val kinesisStreams = (0 until kinesisConfig("numStreams").toInt).map { i =>
    KinesisInputDStream.builder
      .streamingContext(ssc)
      .endpointUrl(kinesisConfig("endpointUrl"))
      .regionName(kinesisConfig("regionName"))
      .streamName(kinesisConfig("streamName"))
      .initialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.LATEST)
      .checkpointAppName(kinesisConfig("appName"))
      .checkpointInterval(Seconds(kinesisConfig("kinesisCheckpointInterval").toInt))
      .storageLevel(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
      .kinesisCredentials(awsCredentials.build())
      .build()
  }
  val unionStreams = ssc.union(kinesisStreams)

  unionStreams.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    if
    (rdd.count()>0){
      println("New records found\nmetrics count in the batch: %s".format(rdd.count()))
      println("performing transformations")
      val str = rdd.map(str => new String(str))
      str.saveAsTextFile("/home/aman/EDA_BP_Kinesis")    
    }
    else
      println("No new record found")
  })    
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()

}
```

> Not Working:

```
 unionStreams.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    if
    (rdd.count()>0){
      println("New records found\nmetrics count in the batch: %s".format(rdd.count()))
      println("performing transformations")
      val str = rdd.map(str => new String(str))
      str.saveAsTextFile("/home/aman/EDA_BP_Kinesis")

      import sparkSession.implicits._
      val records = str.toString()
      val df = sparkSession.read.json(Seq(records).toDS)
      df.count()
      df.show()
    }
    else
      println("No new record found")
  })
```

I've given number of shards as 2, streams as 2 and cores as 4.

Comment: I'm using spark 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Try to create separate Spark Session in foreach. 
Hope this will resolve your deadlock problem.

```
 unionStreams.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    if (rdd.count() > 0) {
      println("New records found\nmetrics count in the batch: %s".format(rdd.count()))
      println("performing transformations")
      val str = rdd.map(str => new String(str))
      str.saveAsTextFile("/home/aman/EDA_BP_Kinesis")
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()

      import spark.implicits._
      val records = str.toString()
      val df = spark.read.json(Seq(records).toDS)
      df.count()
      df.show()
    } else
      println("No new record found")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try increase the number of workers? In case of Spark Streaming with Amazon Kinesis, I believe each shard requires a dedicated worker. So if you have not enough workers, your code does not work.

For why writing to hdfs succeeds? I'm guessing file write operation does not require shuffle so each shard reading worker themselves can handle it. But for `count()` operation, that would need some shuffle so it needs more number of workers.

Comment: Ah, yes. num of `executors`.

Comment: I have a 30 node cluster, so number of executors shouldn't be the issue
Also why I don't get results when I try to use logger.warn("count()") instead of print.
Any idea?